# Treating "N/A" value as null with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am getting data from an external JSON API and parsing the result with Jackson. Unfortunately, that API returns all fields as `String` and those are filled with `"N/A"` when data is unavailable.

I would like to replace those fields with `null`, especially as those are frustrating when I try to convert JSON String fields to more informative Java fields.

A custom `DeserializationProblemHandler` worked for `Integer` fields (see below), but it was useless for Java 8's `LocalDate` fields. Furthermore, it reacts to a problem rather than anticipating it.

I was unable to find a pre-processor to configure into my `ObjectMapper` and am uneasy with the idea of overriding the `BeanDeserializer`.

Do you know of a better/cleaner solution to handle this kind of situations? Thanks!

---

`DeserializationProblemHandler`

```
new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
    @Override
    public Object handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext ctxt, Class<?> targetType, String valueToConvert, String failureMsg) throws IOException {
        return "N/A".equals(valueToConvert) ? null : super.handleWeirdStringValue(ctxt, targetType, valueToConvert, failureMsg);
    }
}
```

---

Error message when processing `"N/A"` in `LocalDate` field

```
Can not deserialize value of type java.time.LocalDate from String "N/A": Text 'N/A' could not be parsed at index 0
```

(works fine when there is date in the data)

Comment: Jackson doesn't generally concern itself with handling specific values of JSON fields. Text based preprocessing may very well be the simplest and most efficient solution for this: `String filteredJson = jsonString.replace("\"N/A\"", "null");`. Otherwise consider catching/handling the Exception.

Comment: I actually thought of it. Just didn't find a way to implement it in my Spring Boot application. All I can do is configure my ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there ought to be a better way of doing this, but the following is the only solution I was able to come up with.

Create a new `JsonDeserializer` that handles "N/A" input. The following example handles strings:

```
public class EmptyStringDeserializer extends StdScalarDeserializer<String> {
    public EmptyStringDeserializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        final String val = parser.getValueAsString();

        if ("N/A".equalsIgnoreCase(val))
            return null;

        return val;
    }
}
```

The class is registered with an `ObjectMapper` like this:

```
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(String.class, new EmptyStringDeserializer());
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(simpleModule);
```

You'll probably want to collect all your converters in a module named for the API that is making you handle things this way.

Comment: Yup, thought of it, went this way. What held my hand is that it prevents me from using Jackson default Deserializers. I have to reimplement all of them. I even tried to make a proxy Deserializer (if "N/A", return null; else call a deserializer), but I don't know which Deserializer Jackson uses for some of my fields.